# Microsoft Project - prevent field autocalculation

Tags: vba, ms-project, calculated-field

What is the possibility of preventing Microsoft Project from calculating the value of the end date field and the duration once we modify the value of the remaining work field.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you mean, how to maintain the duration (and therefore end date) of a task when you change the work value?

To maintain the value of Duration and Forecast Finish date but allow a change to the remaining work value set the Task Type to "Fixed Duration" then set the remaining work value to whatever value you wish.  If you are doing this in VBA it is sensible to declare a variable to hold the task's "Type" value, change it to pjFixedDuration, change the work value (work is stored in minutes so multiply your effort in hours by 60)  then set the task type back to the value you noted.  For example, to set the value of Remaining Work for Task ID 5 in the active project to 2.0 hours, use the following VBA code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim tasktype As Integer
    With ActiveProject.Tasks(5)
        tasktype = .Type
        .Type = pjFixedDuration
        .RemainingWork = 120
        .Type = tasktype
    End With
End Sub
```